# My Python Django program creates a word document and then should (but doesn't) save the document in a Files model

Tags: python, django, django-models, ms-word

There is a Files model, like this:

```py
class Files(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, blank = True, null = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
```

The function that tries to save to this, first creates the word document, which works. It then tries to add the document to the above model, which doesn't work. Here is one of the versions of what I tried:

```py
    doc_name = "Event_" + str(event.pk) + "_Summary.docx"
    doc.save(f'{settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE}/{doc_name}')

    new_file = File(doc)
    print(new_file)
    new_record = Files()
    new_record.name = doc_name
    new_record.event = event
    new_record.document = new_file.file
    new_record.save()
```

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: have you set up ```MEDIA_ROOT``` ??

Comment: Hi Ayush, yes: 
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

The file successfully saves to this directory, but a record in Files DB isn't created.